# Error 'sscanf_result' undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c, function, scanf

Well that's my code and i get this errors

In function 'main':

41  1   [Error] 'scanf_result' undeclared (first use in this function)

41  1   [Note] each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in

```
     #include <stdio.h>
            #include <stdlib.h>


        int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )

      {
        int n;
          float fl,fw,wh,ww,dh,dw;
         float p,t;
        float tl,tw,a;
        float p1,p2,p3;
          printf("What's the width of the floor?");
          scanf ("%d", &fw);
          printf("What's the length of the floor?");
          scanf ("%d", &fl);
             printf("What's the height of the wall?");
              scanf ("%d", &wh);
               printf("What's the width of the wall?");
          scanf ("%d", &ww);
         printf("What's the width of the door?");
          scanf ("%d", &dw);
         printf("What's the height of the door?");
         scanf ("%d", &dh);
          a=fw*fl+(wh*ww)*3-(dh*dw);
      p1=a*22;
         p2=a*23.80;
          p3=a*14;

            char line[100];
          int answer; 
        answer = -1;
        while (answer != 0) 
       {
        printf ("\nWhat tiles do you want?:\n");
          printf (" [1] 20sm X 30sm.");
        printf (" [2] 30sm X 41,6sm");
         printf (" [3] 25sm X 33sm");
         printf ("\nWhat do you want to do? [0 for nothing] ");
          fgets (line, sizeof(line), stdin); 
              scanf_result = scanf (line, "%d", &answer);
            if ((scanf_result == 0) | (scanf_result == EOF))
           {
               printf ("\n *** 1 - 2 or 3! ***\n");
           answer = -1; 
          }
           switch (answer)
        {
                   case 0:
          break;
         case 1:
               printf(" Total price = %.2f lv \n",p1);
         break;
          case 2:
        printf(" Total price = %.2f lv \n",p2);
             break;
           case 3:
             printf(" Total price = %.2f lv \n",p3);
            break;
             default: 
            break;
              }

        }

              system("PAUSE");
           return 0;    
         }
```

Comment: Fix your code formatting and indentation.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own questions.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message clearly describes it, there is no declaration for `scanf_result` variable in your program.

Put a:

```
int scanf_result;
```

in your declaration section to fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
      scanf_result = scanf (line, "%d", &answer);
```

Your `scanf()` usage is wrong. you need [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/scanf.html)   instead.

The `scanf()` function shall read from the standard input stream `stdin`. The `sscanf()` function shall read from the string `line`.

> [Error] 'scanf_result' undeclared (first use in this function)

Error describes what you are missing.

declare `scanf_result`

`sscanf()` returns integer

declare as integer variable.